# I cannot extract correct months and dates?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, data-extraction

I have this column of dataframe as follows:

- Mass Market Paperback,– 1 Oct 1986
- Paperback,– Import, 26 Apr 2018
- Paperback,– 17 Mar 2011
- Paperback,– 2016
- Paperback,– 26 Dec 2011

I want to extract months and years from this list it is a long list. I have executed the following program:

```
def extract_Test(data):
    edition=list(data)
    for i in edition:
        i.split(",-")[1].strip()
        return i
```

However, it is giving me an error saying list index out of range. This data is in a pandas dataframe. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas text functions, also splitter in data is not same like using in your function `–` vs `-`:

```
df['col'].str.split(",–").str[1].str.strip()
```

Comment: Hy Jezrael thank you for helping me. It actually worked I would like to know did it do this if you could tell me thanks!!!

Comment: can you tell me how splitter in data is not same as using in our function??

Comment: @AliMashoud - I think in your function, in my is same like in your data `",–"`

Comment: @AliMashoud - It is `'long'` - `–` and `'short'` `-` value difference